# Qt - C++ - issue sending/receiving data via UDP

Tags: c++, qt, udp, tcp

I am trying to send a message via UDP from a server to a client. I can clearly see in wireshark something is sent and being received. But my Qt application doesn't seem to receive anyting. Could someone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

wireshark screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHZvM.jpg

my code:
**CLIENT**

```
  void udpClient::scanNetwork()

  {

      QByteArray datagram = "my broadcast message ";
  
      socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 2000);

      socket.writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), QHostAddress::Broadcast, 2000);

      qDebug("finished sending");

  }
```

**SERVER**

```
  void udpServer::startListening()
  {
      qDebug("debug ss");
      udpServerObj = new QUdpSocket;

      udpServerObj->bind(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 2000);
      connect(udpServerObj,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
  
  }


  void udpServer::readPendingDatagrams()
  {
      qDebug("received something via UDP");
  
  }
```

the entire code: see comments below, I don't have enough reputation to post multiple links.

Comment: Are you trying to do a UDP broadcast or not?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I'm not sure you should be calling `socket.connectToHost` in your client program. It makes no sense to "connect" to a UDP port, because UDP sockets are connection-less.
2. You shouldn't be sending the datagram to `QHostAddress::Broadcast`. I think you mean to send it to `QHostAddress("127.0.0.1")`. Unless your server socket is listening in promiscuous mode, I wouldn't expect it to see packets destined for the broadcast address.

Comment: strange, as you can see my sender works fime although it is using connectToHost. Next to this after reading the docs, I still think this should be OK. What would you suggest in stead?

That didn't solve the issue btw.

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram) suggests that you should never call `writeDatagram` on a connected socket (see the section marked by "Warning"). Your packet capture shows your client sending to the broadcast address, which again, I wouldn't expect the server to see since it is listening on its host address

Comment: Doesn't a broadcast imply that it is just send to everyone? Which means the server should receive it as well?

Comment: The thing to know about calling `connect()` on a UDP socket is that it installs a sort of incoming-packet-IP-address-filter on that socket, such than even if the UDP packet arrived at the right computer and port, the OS won't actually deliver the incoming UDP packet to the application unless the UDP packet's source-IP field *exactly* matches the IP address that was previously passed to the `connect()` call.    So if your client called `connectToHost(127.0.0.1)`, it won't get any packets coming from any other IP address, even if the machine received them.